# different results when projecting raster with or without aggregate

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, map-projections

My goal is to reproject a raster called `pftnc` to have the same CRS and cell size of another raster `sp`, so they overlap perfectly and can be stacked. Files available here [pftnc](https://ufile.io/6ku1v) and [sp](https://ufile.io/2345k)

I thought it was an issue with software, see the other question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299935/extract-values-from-raster-r-and-arcgis-different-results, but I am having inconsistencies just within R. So I would like to find an R solution first.

I have tried to reproject directly

```
pft1 <- projectRaster(pftnc, sp)
```

And also tried to first aggregate and then reproject

```
pftagg <- aggregate(pftnc, fact=4)
pftproj1 <- projectRaster(from=pftagg, to=sp)
```

I have also tried to just project and then crop and aggregate or the other way around but I can never get to the result I get when I use to=sp, so I abandoned this route.
For example

```
cea=crs(sp)
pftproj2 <- projectRaster(pftnc, crs=cea)
```

The problem is that pftproj1 and pft1 have the same rows,columns,extent, and resolution but the values are different.

```
> cellStats(pftproj1,mean)
[1] 0.1955
> cellStats(pft1,mean)
[1] 0.2028
```

Is there a correct order of operations to achieve this goal? Should I let projectRaster deal with the aggregation of values? I imagine

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a "best" method. I think the main reason for the difference that you get is that if you aggregate first, you get more cells (if aggregating with `na.rm=TRUE`). The difference is much smaller if you use `mask` to compare strictly the same cells.

```
library(raster)
sp <- raster("sp.tif")
pf <- raster("pftnc.tif")

pf1 <- projectRaster(pf, sp)
pfa <- aggregate(pf, fact=4)
pf2 <- projectRaster(from=pfa, to=sp)
pf2m <- mask(pf2, pf1)

# an alternative that I would not recommend
pfr <- projectRaster(pf, crs=crs(sp))
pf3 <- resample(pfr, sp)
pf3m <- mask(pf3, pf1)

cellStats(pf, mean)
#[1] 0.2202417
cellStats(pf1, mean)
#[1] 0.2027533
cellStats(pf2, mean)
#[1] 0.1954503
cellStats(pf2m, mean)
#[1] 0.2024068
cellStats(pf3, mean)
#[1] 0.2016164
cellStats(pf3m, mean)
#[1] 0.2021608
```

In a question it is better to use example data generated by code. In your case, you could use

```
sp <- raster(nrow=142, ncol=360, ext=extent(-17367529, 17367529, -6356742, 7348382), crs="+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")

pf <- raster(ncol=1440, nrow=720, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, crs='+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
values(pf) = rep(c(1:4,NA), ncell(pf)/5)
```

But ... the differences go away, except for the "bad" method. Not sure if this is due to the distribution of your values, or to the role of NA values, but I guess you could experiment to find out.

```
cellStats(pf, mean)
#[1] 2.5
cellStats(pf1, mean)
#[1] 2.5
cellStats(pf2, mean)
#[1] 2.5
cellStats(pf2m, mean)
#[1] 2.5
cellStats(pf3, mean)
#[1] 2.547783
cellStats(pf3m, mean)
[1] 2.547783
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will have to investigate.